# How to change post template via url?

Tags: posts, permalinks, templates, urls

I have a single post template (single.php) which displays the title, the abstract, tags, content etc.
I made another template (abstract.php) to display only the title and the abstract of the post.

1. how to change the link structure for posts' titles in a post list
   from (www.mysite.com/?p=15) to
   (www.mysite.com/?abstract=15). and this will be only in this list page keeping the main structure working.
2. I need the post to be displayed using the second template by url
   parameters. When post url is (www.mysite.com/?p=15),
   the first template will work. while, when post url is
   (www.mysite.com/?abstract=15), the second template will work.

is it possible to do that? Any suggestions please?

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/173513/using-two-permalinks-for-one-post this might help you

Comment: it worked!!!!! but please i need to know how to add "flush rewrite rules" to the code as it was mentioned in that answer.

Comment: i tried to replace "play" with "abstract" .. but it didn't work. it returned the single post template. can you help me with that please?

Comment: Try updating your permalink structure. Go to Settings / Permalinks and simply hit save, that will flush your rewrite rules, might fix the issue.

Comment: Greaaaaaaaaat, you are great thanks a lot it worked :)