# how to use two permalinks for one custom post type based on categories

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, permalinks, rewrite-rules

I am trying to get 2 different permalink for one custom post type, based on the solution given [there](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/196063/how-to-use-two-permalinks-for-one-custom-post-type/223308#223308). It is working for articles, but I can't get it work for my "film" custom post type.

Here is my code, with my 3 categories (international ; france ; projections_dvd) :

```
function wpd_query_var( $query_vars ) {
    $query_vars[] = 'is_international';
    $query_vars[] = 'is_france';
    $query_vars[] = 'is_projections_dvd';
    return $query_vars;
}
add_filter('query_vars', 'wpd_query_var' , 10, 1 );

function wpd_post_rewrite(){
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'international/([^/]+)/?$',
        'index.php?name=$matches[1]&is_international=1',
        'top'
    );
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'france/([^/]+)/?$',
        'index.php?name=$matches[1]&is_france=1',
        'top'
    );
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'projections_dvd/([^/]+)/?$',
        'index.php?name=$matches[1]&is_projections_dvd=1',  
        'top'
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpd_post_rewrite' );

function wpd_abstract_template( $single_template ){
    global $wp_query;
    //print_r($wp_query);

    if ( isset( $wp_query->query_vars['is_international'] ) ) {
      if(in_category('international')) { 
        return locate_template( 'film_international_template.php', false ) ; 
      } else { 
        return locate_template( '404.php', false ) ;
      }    
    } 

    if ( isset( $wp_query->query_vars['is_france'] ) ) {
      if(in_category('france')) { 
        return locate_template( 'film_france_template.php', false ) ; 
      } else { 
        return locate_template( '404.php', false ) ;
      }    
    } 

    if ( isset( $wp_query->query_vars['is_projections_dvd'] ) ) {
      if(in_category('projections_dvd')) { 
        return locate_template( 'film_projections_dvd_template.php', false ) ; 
      } else { 
        return locate_template( '404.php', false ) ;
      }    
    } 

    return locate_template( 'single.php', false ) ; 

}
add_filter( 'single_template', 'wpd_abstract_template' );
```

So my "example" article is displayed at both permalinks with different templates : 
www.mysite.com/international/example
www.mysite.com/france/example

But my post "example" of custom post type "film" (which has both "france" and "international" categories) still have this only default permalink : www.mysite.com/film/example
I would need it to have those 2 permalinks : www.mysite.com/international/film/example and www.mysite.com/france/film/example
or at least www.mysite.com/international/example and www.mysite.com/france/example

I have searched for a solution and I am a bit lost, if anyone have a clue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone's interested, the solution was quite close, I only had to specify the rewrite rule with &post_type=film :

```
add_rewrite_rule(
    'projections_dvd/([^/]+)/?$',
    'index.php?name=$matches[1]&post_type=film&is_projections_dvd=1',  
    'top'
);
```

I also changed the query vars to make it simpler :

```
function wpd_query_var( $query_vars ) {
    $query_vars[] = 'is_international';
    $query_vars[] = 'is_france';
    $query_vars[] = 'is_projections_dvd';
    $query_vars[] = 'categorie';
    return $query_vars;
}
add_filter('query_vars', 'wpd_query_var' , 10, 1 );

function wpd_post_rewrite(){
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'international/([^/]+)/?$',
        'index.php?name=$matches[1]&post_type=film&categorie=international',  
        'top'
    );
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'france/([^/]+)/?$',
        'index.php?name=$matches[1]&post_type=film&categorie=france',  
        'top'
    );
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'projections_dvd/([^/]+)/?$', 
        'index.php?name=$matches[1]&post_type=film&categorie=projections_dvd',  
        'top'
    );
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'international/theatrical/([^/]+)/?$',
        'index.php?name=$matches[1]&post_type=film&categorie=theatrical',  
        'top'
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpd_post_rewrite' );

function wpd_abstract_template( $single_template ){
    global $wp_query;

    if ( isset( $wp_query->query_vars['categorie'] ) ) {
      $categorie = $wp_query->query_vars['categorie'] ;
      if($categorie == 'international' && in_category('international')) {
        return locate_template( 'film_international_template.php', false ) ; 
      } elseif($categorie == 'theatrical' && in_category('theatrical')) {
        return locate_template( 'film_international_theatrical_template.php', false ) ; 
      } elseif($categorie == 'france' && in_category('france')) {
        return locate_template( 'film_france_template.php', false ) ; 
      } elseif($categorie == 'projections_dvd' && in_category('projections_dvd')) {
        return locate_template( 'film_projections_dvd_template.php', false ) ; 
      } else { 
        return locate_template( '404.php', false ) ;
      } 
    } 
    return locate_template( 'single.php', false ) ; 

}
add_filter( 'single_template', 'wpd_abstract_template' );
```